# Swift TextKit2 get substring from an NSTextRange

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, textkit

I have a `UITextView` and a `NSTextRange`. How can I get a simple `String` corresponding to the range?

I can only see `uiTextView.text(in: UITextRange)` but I am not sure if `NSTextRange` and `UITextRange` are even comparable, or how to map one to the other.

Context on why I'm trying to do this:
I have some text in the `UITextView` and I want to figure out what portion of the text did fit the frame and which portion did not. So I do:

```
let textLayoutManager = textView.textLayoutManager!
let rangeOfRenderedText: NSTextRange = textLayoutManager.textLayoutFragment(for: CGPointZero)!.rangeInElement
let rangeOfRemainderText: NSTextRange = NSTextRange(location: rangeOfRenderedText.endLocation)

let stringThatFit: String = // use rangeOfRenderedText somehow
let stringThatDidNotFit: String = // use rangeOfRemainderText somehow
```

Comment: Why don't you use `NSRange`?

Comment: @ElTomato how do I do that if the range returned from the `textLayoutFragment` is a `NSTextRange`?